# Netcdf4 over Nodejs

Tags: node.js, npm, netcdf4

I am trying install netcdf4 over nodejs in windows10. 
Gave the npm install netcdf4 and get the following errors. I am installing it as as an administrator and ncdump works from command line.

C:\Windows\node_modules\netcdf4>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin\....\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "/m" switch.

```
Group.cpp
  File.cpp
  Variable.cpp
  Dimension.cpp
c:\windows\node_modules\netcdf4\src\Variable.h(4): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'netcdf.h': No such fil
e or directory (compiling source file ..\src\Variable.cpp) [C:\Windows\node_modules\netcdf4\build\netcdf4.vcxproj]
  Attribute.cpp
..\src\Dimension.cpp(2): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'netcdf.h': No such file or directory [C:\Windows
\node_modules\netcdf4\build\netcdf4.vcxproj]
  netcdf4js.cpp
..\src\Group.cpp(2): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'netcdf.h': No such file or directory [C:\Windows\nod
e_modules\netcdf4\build\netcdf4.vcxproj]
  win_delay_load_hook.cc
..\src\File.cpp(2): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'netcdf.h': No such file or directory [C:\Windows\node
_modules\netcdf4\build\netcdf4.vcxproj]
..\src\Attribute.cpp(3): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'netcdf.h': No such file or directory [C:\Windows
\node_modules\netcdf4\build\netcdf4.vcxproj]
```

Glan